# Returning PK from table, where FK appears more than once

Tags: sql

I was asked to return all property_id's (PK), where the customer owns more than one property (property_id, FK). Here is the table for visual reference:

[image: CustomerPropertiesTable]

How would I do this in valid SQL syntax? My thought process went something like this:

```
SELECT property_id FROM CustomerProperties
WHERE COUNT(property_id) > 1
```

Which is clearly not valid, but that's my OOP thought process.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Re: Images of code - does that count for DB table representations too?

I'm using MS SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the expected results from your sample table image would be 1, 4.

Something like this should get you started.

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE 
(
    PropertyId  INT PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerId  INT
);

INSERT @Test ( PropertyId, CustomerId ) 
VALUES ( 1, 1 ), ( 2, 2 ), (3, 3 ), ( 4, 1 );

SELECT
    PropertyId
FROM 
    @Test
WHERE 
    CustomerId IN
    ( 
        SELECT 
            CustomerId 
        FROM 
            @Test
        GROUP BY 
            CustomerId
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    );
```

The second part of the query finds customers that have more than one property.

Comment: Yes that is the expect result.

Thank you! I can confirm that this works well.

Would you be able to explain the "IN" clause part? I'm failing to understand how it knows to check for more than one property_id's, as property_id isn't specified within the grouping.

Comment: Here is documentation on T-SQL IN clause.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/in-transact-sql   Play with the sample data and run the sub-query independently, I think it will become apparent to you how the IN clause works.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the column you want to be unique and select only those groups having a count > 1

```
SELECT property_id 
FROM CustomerProperties
GROUP BY property_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

When you group then all aggregate functions like COUNT() apply to each group and not the complete result set. And the HAVING clause is used for for group wide conditions while the WHERE clause is for record conditions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Unfortunately it isn't working for me though. Shouldn't the GROUP BY clause be for the customer_id since that's the column we want to check for >1 records?

Thanks again.

Comment: Not working is way too vague. What exactly is not working?